# Поломался QT Creator 5.10

Tags: c++, qt5

Версия IDE:
Qt Creator 4.5.0
Основан на Qt 5.10.0 (MSVC 2015, 32 бита)
Собрано Dec 4 2017 в 04:12:22
Ревизия fcea6ceba6

Добавил в конструктор mainwindow строчку

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "UTF8");
```

и перекомпилировал проект. 
После этого при попытке компиляции любого заведомо работающего проекта в любом режиме выдаёт ошибку:

> [tr]Error 1

Не помогает ни перезапуск IDE не перезагрузка компьютера.
Кто нибудь знает - как починить, кроме как переустановить QT Creator?

после переустановки на версию QT 5.12.7 ошибка во вкладке "Проблемы" конкретизировалась:

> :-1: ошибка: [Makefile.Debug:147: tr] Error 1

Comment: дык это же локаль а не кодировка. надо было setlocale (LC_ALL, "ru_RU.UTF-8");

Comment: Или убрать нахрен setlocale или удалить файл qtcreator_ru.qm переведя его на аглицкий язык

Comment: Фишка в том, что никакие отмены и запуск других, заведомо исправных проектов, которые раньше нормально писались, компилировались и работали в этой среде - не помогает. При попытке любой компиляции вылетает эта ошибка. Разумеется первое, что я пробовал - отменить последние изменения.

Comment: "выдаёт ошибку" - кто выдает ошибку? где она выдается? При чем тут `setlocale` если ошибка при сборке? почему бы не переустановить, если это проблема с самим креатором?

Comment: Вопрос был задан на случай, если кто-либо знает быстрое решение возникшей проблемы. Переустановка занимает много времени. Но в общем я понял, что никто из заглянувших не знает ответа. Поэтому процесс переустановки я уже начал. Но если найдется человек, который знает решение кроме переустановки среды или компилятора - было бы неплохо, чтобы он поделился.

Comment: После переустановки на версию 5.12.7 ошибка конкретизировалась: :-1: ошибка: [Makefile.Debug:147: tr] Error 1

Answer (score -1):

Если в .pro файле проекта закоментировать строку PRE_TARGETDEPS += tr

```
tr.commands = lupdate \"$$_PRO_FILE_\" && lrelease \"$$_PRO_FILE_\"
#    PRE_TARGETDEPS += tr
    QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += tr
```

то проект компилируется и запускается.
Проблемы возникли при подключении статических библиотек для многоязыковой поддержки (моё приложение по заданию должно работать на нескольких языках, потому без них мне не обойтись).